# Merge tag [linqjs] into [linq.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[linqjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linqjs) is the same as [linq.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq.js).

Can this tags be merged?

Comment: Just 4 questions there ... done.